# Convert DB2 SQL expression to Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2

Can anyone tell me the meaning of this query below? 
Also I'm trying to ocnvert this query into its SQL Server equivalent. Any help if greatly appreciated. Not familiar with Locate function or what the use of '||' means in DB2
DBstring is a column in the DB/
I'm on SQL Server 2012

```
 SUBSTR(DBstring, LOC('5'||CHR(9)||'CH', DBstring) + 2, 2) = 'CH'
```

I know SUBSTR is SUBSTRING in SQL Server. I think SQL SERVER has a LOCATE function.
Specifically I'm not sure what this part of the query is doing ' LOC('5'||CHR(9)||'CH', DBstring) + 2'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `loc` is equivalent to `locate`.  The expression in SQL Server would be:

```
substr(dbstring, charindex('5'+CHAR(9)+'CH', DBstring) + 2, 2) = 'CH'
```

Comment: Just tried that but I get this error: The data types varchar and char are incompatible in the '|' operator.

Comment: Sorry about that . . . I left in the '||' instead of '+' for string concatenation.